# Android: possible to unicast an intent?

Tags: android

In Android, is it possible to unicast an `Intent` to an `Activity`? The only options I see for sending intents is either to start an activity or issue a broadcast, but I only want a specific target to receive my Intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to set a specific [`ComponentName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setComponent%28android.content.ComponentName%29) via either a constructor or the `setComponent` and `setClassName` methods.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try to 
specify your intent and put private `BroadcastReceiver` in your target?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Declare your Activity without any Intent filters:

```
<activity android:name=".MapActivity">
</activity>
```

Then send your startActivity with an Intent that has a component name:

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("package.name","package.name.MapActivity");
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(comp);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

You could also put a different application's Activity in the ComponentName field.

More about this [here](http://gradgrind.erso.berkeley.edu/blog/?p=100).

Answer (score 0):

From dev guide about [intent resolution](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ires) seems that with explicit intents you get the behavior you're searching for:

> Explicit intents designate the target
>   component by its name […] explicit
>   intents are typically used for
>   application-internal messages

As long as you're specifying the target the system should not search for a match among registered filters:

> In the absence of a designated target,
>   the Android system must find the best
>   component (or components) to handle
>   the intent

Also, as you asked about sending a message to an Activity, it's worth noticing:

> There is no overlap within these
>   messaging systems: Broadcast intents
>   are delivered only to broadcast
>   receivers, never to activities or
>   services. An intent passed to
>   startActivity() is delivered only to
>   an activity, never to a service or
>   broadcast receiver, and so on.